# Ocultar div quando clicar nela

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Como posso fazer para clicar na div e parar de exibi-la? estou usando o onClick mas não está executando.

Minha div:

```
<div class='alert alert-danger aviso' role='alert' style='width: 20%;'>Falha ao carregar os dados!</div>
```

onClick:

```
$('.aviso').on("click", function () {
                    $('.aviso').hide();
                }
```

Comment: Dá algum erro no console? E, por favor, elabore um [mcve] do seu problema utilizando o snippet do site (botão `</>` do editor).

Comment: Não consegue esconder pq está faltando fechar a função com o **)** depois do **}**. Provavelmente se abrir o console **(f12)** verá o erro impresso nele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você colocou seu código completo, está faltando fechar a atribuição do click, falta um `);` no final. Acredito que seja isso porque coloquei seu código num fiddle e funcionou, e aqui no snippet também:

```js
$('.aviso').on("click", function () {
  $('.aviso').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='alert alert-danger aviso' role='alert' style='width: 20%;'>Falha ao carregar os dados!</div>
```

Aliás, para garantir que vai fechar somente o `div` que foi clicado, sugiro substituir a linha `$('.aviso').hide();` por `$(this).hide();`

Answer (score 0):

[Exemplo de hide com jquery](https://codepen.io/thiago-henrique-gomes/pen/wxZxYM)

Ainda pode ser adicionado outros tipos de animações. Por default ela é swing.